# Finding keywords in image data

Tags: php, image, exif

I kinda ran into a problem, I'm working on a small image site for a photographer, the photographer uses photoshop to store information into the image.
Information such as image data, location, descriptions, ...

He's been doing this since CS3.

When user uploads a picture to the site, he wants everything to go automatically, so I was trying to read out all the keywords, like this:

```
$size = getimagesize($path, $info);
if(isset($info['APP13'])) {
    $iptc = iptcparse($info['APP13']);

    if(isset($iptc['2#025'])) {
        $tagsArr = $iptc['2#025'];
    } else {
         $tagsArr = array();
    }
}
```

This all works fine for images saved in CS5, but for images saved in CS3 it fails, even though I'm 100% sure the keywords are in there.

To give an example:
This one fails - http://woutr.be/naturalight/uploads/ea568fea3e7eb1448d30fb823f477aac.jpg
This one works - http://woutr.be/naturalight/uploads/e3f2e6db833803a77eb75aae16e8c8ec.jpg

I've been looking into this for a few days, but I can't figure out why this doesn't work for some images.

Comment: Define fails? What does `print_r($iptc)` give you?

Comment: Not much actually, just some other information, no keywords (http://pastebin.com/NXAnBwKf)

Comment: I also tried a library such as http://www.ozhiker.com/electronics/pjmt/index.html, but this gives me the same problem

Comment: I have Photoshop CS3 on Window. Your failed image works after editing the image metadata (ie. remove one of the words). It could be that the photoshop the client is using creates an invalid metadata.

Comment: I told him about that, he said he used a site before where it was possible. (But can't remember which site that was)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know you had mentioned that you tried ozhiker's code before, but I was able to pull a full list of keywords from both images using Photoshop_File_Info.php

http://www.ozhiker.com/electronics/pjmt/download.html

From file 1:

`amphibian
aquatic
belgium
close-up
common frog
europe
frog
froglet
leaf
metamorphosis
pond
reproduction
silhouette
spring
veins
water
waterplantsamfibie
belgie
blad
bruine kikker
europa
kikker
kikkervisje
metamorfose
nerven
poel
silhouet
vijver
voorjaar
voortplanting
watermilieu
waterplanten`

From file 2:

`finland
abstract
boom
tree
bomen
trees
boomstam
dromerig
effect
soft
zacht
kleur
colour
lijnen
lines
patroon
pattern
patronen
patterns
scenic
picturesque
sfeer
atmosphere
bos
forest
naaldhout
conifer
pine forest
blauw
blue
lijnen
lines
sparrenbos
fijnsparrenbos
firtree
spar
fijnspar
picea abies
norway spruce
habitat
national park
alps
europe
nationaal park
nature
natuur
woud
vegetatie
plant
vegetation
planting
tree
boom
boslandschap
wildernis
monochrome
movement
beweging`

Comment: Could you give me some more information on this? I also used Photoshop_File_Info, but I wasn't able to get the keywords from both images.

Comment: In ozhiker's code structure, use the `Example.php?jpeg_fname=` in the folder root.   When you point the `jpeg_fname` to your image file it displays all of the keywords in the `Contains Extensible Metadata Platform (XMP) / Resource Description Framework (RDF) Information` section.  Let me know if you need any further info.

Comment: Hmmm, I must be doing something totally wrong then, I just get the error "Bad image filename defined - Must be jpg or jpeg". The image is a .jpg ...

Comment: Either the regex was wrong, or it just doesn't work on my server, but after removing that piece, I was able to get all the keywords from both images

Comment: How would I go about adding new keywords to the image?

Answer (score 1):

I just examined both of your files and the failing file does not have the keywords that the working file has. The failing file describes a "Rana Temporaria" without keywords, while the working file describes a "Pine Forest" with a long list of keywords such as "alps, vegetation, nature". They both have a JPEG APP13 data segment, but the contents of those segments are quite different.

Comment: The keywords are different in both files, but they are there.
When I check the file info in photoshop, I can see the keywords in both files. (Even just in Finder on Mac I can see them)

Is there any way to get the keywords out by php? My existing method only seems to work for one of the files

Answer (score 0):

Did you try the `exif_` functions. They can read the headers of an image.

http://php.net/manual/en/book.exif.php